# Sony Vegas Pro 12/17 большие видеофайлы

Tags: vegas

Раньше проблем не было, использовал 12-тую версию. Но сейчас в руки попал 6-ти часовой 6-ти гигабайтный стрим, который попросту отказывается лезть в вегас. Вегас зависает при начале обработке видеофайла. Ну. Скачал также 17-тую - результат тот же. Тут пока растерялся - либо видео делить пополам через `ffmpeg`, либо как-то расковеркать Вегас. Обязательно гуглил, но там только увеличение `RAM` на `Preview`, что абсолютно мою проблему не решает.

Мое железо (на всякий):

> 16 GB RAM DDR4
> i5-6500T

Конкретизирую 2 возникших вопроса:

1. Как разрезать видео пополам через `ffmpeg`?
2. Возможно ли заставить `Vegas Pro` обработать мое видео?

Comment: Уточните какой формат файла и какой кодек использует файл, как видео, так и аудио.

Comment: @B1aZe, видео `mpeg4`

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант решения, пройдите в папку, где установлен `Vegas`, там откройте папку `FileIO Plug-Ins` найдите там файл с названием `compoundplug.dll`, переместите этот файл в любую другую папку, либо создайте новую и переместите туда этот файл. Этот файл отвечает за прочтение файлов, он может конфликтовать с другими плагинами, по этому Вегас и зависает.

Comment: Теперь формат `.mp4` не определяется. Пробовал на 17 версии. Есть смысл на 12 пробовать?

Comment: Видимо проблема все-же в предосмтре

Comment: Попробуйте видео разрезать на 10 секунд и запихнуть в Вегас, что он скажет на это. Соответственно верните этот файл обратно и попробуйте так сделать.

Comment: Я режу по 2 часа (там не 5 часов, а 5.59, т.е. 6). Буду пробовать.

Comment: При разбиении главного файла на субфайлы все стало работать хорошо.